# Morphisms between cones

Tags: category-theory

Given following diagram and assuming that triangles $CD_iD_j$, $CC'D_i$, $CC'D_j$ commute, does it follow that the fourth triangle, $C'D_iD_j$, commute?

[image: Diagram of cones]

I can show that $c_j' \circ m = D_f \circ c_i' \circ m$, but that doesn't seem to imply that $c_j' = D_f \circ c_i'$, which is what I'm aiming for.

Motivation: I want to convince myself that a morphism $m: C \rightarrow C'$ with the property $c_j' \circ m = c_j$, for all $j$, is a morphism between cones, that is, if $c_j = D_f \circ c_i$ then $c_j' = D_f \circ c_i'$.

Sorry for the simple question; I'm sure there is something fundamental that eludes me.

Comment: I think I've realised my mistake: the objects in the Cone category are cones by definition, so there is no need to prove anything. Still, I don't understand why we can't  define morphisms in the Cone category to be any morphism between $C$ and $C'$.

Comment: Because, indeed, there would be no reason for an arbitrary $m$ to have any useful relationship with the $D_i$, so you'd just be talking about morphisms in the base category, rather than morphisms between *cones* in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Right. Thanks a lot for helping me out!